# efficient viewport using scrolling

Tags: optimization, pygame

i have this function to be able to not need to re blit the screen for smooth scrolling , it compensates     for the right menu by blitting over the parts of it that get scrolled onto the viewport (located at 0,0 and 640 by     640p) the surface i am using is 680 by 680 , how do i correctly account for the menu
it should not blit the whole viewport every frame for performance concerns

```
    def optimized_blit(source, dest, position,frametime,xt=0,xtd=0):
        global phash,phashx
    #     
    #     if viewportx.__class__.__name__ == 'str':
    #         viewportx = viewport.Viewport(position[0],position[1],source,dest)
        
    #         viewportx.sc(position[0],position[1])
        if (frametime%4)==1 or xt==1:
            source.set_alpha(255)
            #dest.blit(source,position)
            phash = position
            dest.blit(source,position)
        elif not xt==1:
            if not str(phash) == str(position):
                #new_position = ( phash[0]-position[0] , position[1] - phash[1])
                #visible_width = min(680 - new_position[0], 680)
                #ufr = 640-(position[0]-phash[0])
                #sca = position[0] - phash[0]
                x_p = min((640-position[0])-5,679)
                y_p = 0
                rect = (x_p,y_p,5,640)
                dest.scroll(position[0] - phash[0], position[1] - phash[1])
                print(rect)
                #print
                if x_p>0 and y_p>0:
                    #time.sleep(0.1)
                    print(rect)
                    dest.blit(source.subsurface(rect),(635,0))
                    print()

            
                phash = position
                xtract = [640-position[0],680-phash[0]]
                #print(xtract)
            #print(phash)
        #positionx = [int(i) for i in position]
        #if not phas
        if  xtd:
             phashx = position
             phash = position
             #phash = position
             #print(position)
             dest.blit(source,position)
    #viewportx.draw(dest)
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the change of sca = position[0] - phash[0] directly and add it to position[0] to optain the right rectangle
like this

```
sca = position[0] - phash[0]
rect = (x_p,y_p,position[0]+sca,640)
```